# JUnit java.nio.file.FileSystemAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I am making a piece of software that runs a load test using the JUnit launcher. The problem is that I keep on encountering the following warning `WARNING: Error scanning files for URI jar: ...` with exception `java.nio.file.FileSystemAlreadyExistsException` emitted from the JUnit code base due to `jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:102)` at `org.junit.platform.commons.util.CloseablePath.createForJarFileSystem(CloseablePath.java:57)`.

I am launching the same test across multiple threads. I believe the issue is caused by the `.execute()` method performing test discovery each time, causing a race condition inside the JUnit code.

I was wondering if there is there currently a way to perform test discovery once in JUnit and then use the same `TestPlan` to execute the test multiple times? If not is then is there a fix for this problem that allows me to invoke tests which are packaged in the `.jar` format (unzipping the test `.jar` is not feasible for my use case).

It seems to me that JUnit no longer supports executing the same test plan repeatedly https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2379 forcing inefficient test discovery to happen each time leading to the `FileSystemAlreadyExistsException`. The following class in JUnit may not be thread safe https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/junit-platform-commons/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/commons/util/CloseablePath.java

Thanks!